# Struggling with online connection but working offline

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

```
public Database Db()
{
    string serverName = "host\\SQLEXPRESS;";
    string dbName = "db";
    string username = "user";
    string password = "123";

    var connectionstring = "Data Source=" + serverName +
                     ";Initial Catalog=" + dbName +
                     ";User ID=" + username +
                     ";Password=" + password +
                     ";Max Pool Size=200;Pooling=true" +
                     ";Connect Timeout=20";

    return new Database(connectionstring , "System.Data.SqlClient");
}
```

This will return something like the following:

```
string conn = Data Source=host\\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=DbName;User ID=UserName;
Password=Pass;Max Pool Size=200;Pooling=true;Connect Timeout=20
```

The error shows that the server was not found or was not accessible I opened certain ports and connect to it several times but once the app is uploaded the problem starts.

Comment: you server name looks weird to me. Do you mean localhost?

Comment: "host" depends on whether its online or localhost assume its server name(online)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string serverName = @".\SQLEXPRESS;";
string dbName = "db";
string username = "user";
string password = "123";

var connectionstring = "Data Source=" + serverName +
                    ";Initial Catalog=" + dbName +
                    ";User ID=" + username +
                    ";Password=" + password +
                    ";Max Pool Size=200;Pooling=true" +
                    ";Connect Timeout=20";
```

The serverName variable have been slightly changed and I removed a semicolon.

Comment: didn't work, but development i tested it without the "." replace with online ip and it connected

Comment: ok, so then you are not connecting to a db on your local machine. The dot (.) means localhost basically.